# How to auto-refresh page with browser-sync and Gulp

Tags: html, css, gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to auto-refresh my page when I make changes with `broswer-sync` and `gulp`.

So far I have it working with my `html` but I can't seem to figure it out with my `css` code too.

I have this line of code in my `gulpfile.js` that works quite well with *ONLY* `html`.

`gulp.watch("*.html").on("change", reload);`

Any help? Thanks! I've also tried putting `*.css` into the `.watch()` function and had no luck. I also have a folder with my `css` in it named "css".

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution!

You **cannot** see changes with javascript nor CSS. If you want that you'll need to do a live server following *https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-live-server*

**EDIT**

Go download live server in VSCode, you're welcome...

Comment: You don't need that package to use browsersync and gulp to live update changes to javascript and CSS